# error No view found for id 0x6af (unknown) for fragment, When i try to put flagment into Recyclerview Item on Adapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have an error: 
No view found for id 0x7f090054 for fragment PersonFragment
When i am try make new id for Recyclerview Container of new Fragment.

```
public class BookRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BookRecyclerAdapter.RecyclerViewHolder> {

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewHolder holder, int position) {
    //bind view...

    // Delete previous added fragment
    int currentContainerId = holder.mLayoutContainer.getId();
    Fragment oldFragment = mFragmentManager.findFragmentById(currentContainerId);
    if (oldFragment != null) {
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().remove(oldFragment).commit();
    }

    // Make new Id for container of Fragment
    int newContainerId = getUniqueId();
    holder.mLayoutContainer.setId(newContainerId);

    if (position == 0) {
        // add fragment by code
        PersonFragment personFragment = PersonFragment.newInstance(3);
        mFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(newContainerId, personFragment).commit();
    }
}
```

When i try with TextView, it ok, I can get new Id for TextView. But when i try with Container of Fragment it make error.

Comment: This is a BAD idea. Use a Compound View.See https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html for more information.

Comment: I using NestedScrollView and AppBarLayout for replace this. NestedScrollView view container 2 Fragment, and RecyclerView. But Recycler don't scroll smoth, it load a lot of child. AppBarLayout is fix a lot of background, it is hard to handle. So i find this solution.